# Automatically detect different zones in a scatterplot and then extract and use a specific one for further plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am developing a shiny app, in which I am generating various scatterplots from a data frame.
I want the app to be able to detect different zones of the scatterplot. And then user should be able to select the zone of interest.
For e.g.
[image]

As you can see in the picture, blue colour points are the scatter points.
And I want the app to be able to detect different zones as shown in the picture.
For now, I am just drawing some vertical lines and horizontal lines in order to subset the required zone for further plotting. This method is very hectic because in every case the data varies so the location of the required zone also varies.

I tried using `plotly_brush` feature, it works but its not an ideal way for me.

Is there any way to detect different zones in a scatterplot automatically and use a specific zone for further processing?

PS. I could not include my data frames in this question because they are too big.

Here is my attempt:

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    df <- read.table(file=input$file$datapath[input$file$name==input$Select], skip = 15, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    return(df)
  })

      x1 <- data()[, c(input$xcol1, input$ycol1)]
      x1[x1 == ""] <- NA
      M <- na.omit(x1)
      #plot
      g <- ggplot(data =  M) + theme_bw() +
        geom_point(aes_string(x= M[,1], y= (M[,2]-min(M[1,2]))),colour = "blue", size =0.1)
      g
```

Comment: Hi OP.  Can you share a reprex and some code for your app?  If your data frames are too big, no problem - share an example that can illustrate your problem using `mtcars`, `diamonds`, or any of the other built-in datasets.

Comment: Please share your coding attempts so far. Your algorithm may be somewhat involved and SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Yes, I will provide my attempt of the code.

Comment: Search for "changepoint detection in R", there are several packages.